# How to know how many icons a .dll file contains (by importing the file from the computer) C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know if it is possible to find out **how many icons a .dll file stores** by importing a file from the user's computer. I will explain in detail what I want to do. I need to know how many icons the .dll file contains because I'm using a **listview** where it's going to put the icons that this .dll file contains because when this form starts, it's going to display the icons to the user, and the number of icons that are going to be displayed in the listview is what I'm going to need to display those icons.

What I want to do is that the user can import his own .dll file from his computer. My program can read a .dll file or icon. But I have to tell it the path to the .dll file and when I add a .dll file, I use a program, not just any program, it is GConvert 5. It's great for saving icons from the .dll file in any format but I use it to know how many icons are in this .dll file I opened with. After I know this, I add one line of code per icon (from starting with 0 to (the number of icons in the .dll file)). But how can I know how many icons a .dll file contains when I am not behind the user's computer? I did this:

- Adding an OpenFileDialog from the ToolBox
- Adding the extensions: dll and ico
- In the code, I add that:

  ```
  if (MyOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
  {
      string dllFile = MyOpenFileDialog.FileName; // Ok, now I have the .dll file but I still can't find out how many icons this dll file contains.

      //... (Some code that is necessary and will not destroy the counting of icons)
  }
  ```

But I can't find any solutions on Google, tried some code but if I come to stackoverflow, my code doesn't works.

Thanks for helping me!

I tried to use a loop to display the icons in the listview but it doesn't work, I expect the user to open the .dll file, and in the listview it will simply show the number of icons in that listview.

Comment: do dll files necessarily contain icons?

Comment: No but if the user open a dll file with icons, I need that.

Comment: can you give some links(preferably from microsoft) that describe how icons are stored in dlls?

Comment: Ok I just searched  but still didin't find anything on Google. I don't really know ther are storeed

Comment: Hmm.... Too hard to answer that... I don't really understand what you wan to sah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the icons and count of icons using [ExtractIconEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticonexw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) function:

```
[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
private static extern int ExtractIconEx(
    string lpszFile,
    int nIconIndex,
    IntPtr[] phiconLarge,
    IntPtr[] phiconSmall,
    int nIcons);
```

To get the count of icons in the file, pass `nIconIndex= -1` and `nIcons = 0`, and the return value will be the count of icons. Later, initialize the desired array with the count that you received in the previous step and pass `nIconIndex= 0` and `nIcons = count of icons`.

**Example**

Here is a very quick example that shows how you can get icons from `shell32.dll` and show them in a list veiw:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
private static extern int ExtractIconEx(
    string lpszFile,
    int nIconIndex,
    IntPtr[] phiconLarge,
    IntPtr[] phiconSmall,
    int nIcons);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var count = ExtractIconEx("shell32.dll",
        -1, null, null, 0);
    var phiconLarge = new IntPtr[count];
    var phiconSmall = new IntPtr[count];
    var result = ExtractIconEx("shell32.dll",
        0, phiconLarge, null, count);
    ImageList imagelist1 = new ImageList();
    imagelist1.ImageSize = SystemInformation.IconSize;
    imagelist1.Images.AddRange(
        phiconLarge.Select(x => Icon.FromHandle(x).ToBitmap()).ToArray());
    var listView1 = new ListView();
    listView1.LargeImageList = imagelist1;
    listView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
    listView1.Items.AddRange(
        Enumerable.Range(0, count)
        .Select(x => new ListViewItem(x.ToString(), x)).ToArray());
    this.Controls.Add(listView1);
    phiconLarge.ToList().ForEach(x => DestroyIcon(x));
}
```

And this is what you get:

[image]

Please pay attention to the point which is highlighted in the comments by Jimi as per [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticonexw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks) to destroy icon handles as soon as you don't need them: *When they are no longer needed, you must destroy all icons extracted by ExtractIconEx by calling the DestroyIcon function.*

Comment: OK! Nice. Just one thing that's not really problematic but it doesn't clear the images but I just add that before the code: `listView1.Clear();` and `imageList1.Images.Clear();` so it will remove the used icons if you have options to load another dll or export one.

Comment: And if it is possible, I need a DragAndDrop support. I don't remember how to support a drag and drop to a listview, I turned on the setting "AllowDrop" in the Form's settings. There are event handlers in the Events tab of the properties of the listview that matter with drag and drop. I just need a drag and drop support for the listview. Thanks! (I searched but lose op...)

Comment: these are nothing related to dll and icons. you could ask anther question.